# How can I force Visual Studio to use dependency library names I want it to?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I've created a static c++ library in Visual Studio (2013) called "mylib.lib".  It is multi-threaded (/MT) and I specify the "output file" under Librarian/General to be "$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)" so I can name it without the "mt" Visual Studio wants to force onto the end of the file name just because I used '/MT'.

This project also links in several other dependencies so they're all in one giant "mylib.lib" file for consumption by using applications.  These other librarys are "A.lib", "B.lib", and "C.lib". They are also built specifying the output name so as not to have "mt" on the end of their file names.

Now I want to consume "mylib.lib" in a C++ application that also uses '/MT' to build.  The application links with that library and calls a single function within it.  The application fails to link because it "cannot open file 'Amt.lib' LNK1104".

The application doesn't have a direct dependency on "A.lib" and that dependency is already contained in "mylib.lib" which it DOESN'T try to link as "mylibmt.lib".  The seemingly arbitrary decision to apply the "mt" suffix in one case and not another is confusing.

What is going on inside Visual Studio's mind here?  And is there a way I can tell it to NOT append "mt" onto certain libraries?

Comment: "This project also links in several other dependencies so they're all in one giant "mylib.lib" file for consumption by using applications." lib files don't _link_ to other lib files.

Comment: @tkausl: [They do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47719975/how-can-i-force-visual-studio-to-use-dependency-library-names-i-want-it-to), sort of.

Comment: mylib.lib is pretty massive after building so I'm pretty sure they're in there...?  Either way, I would still need it to not put "mt" on the end of the name.

Comment: A -1 downvote? For what?

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to set "No default libraries" in the consuming application and then manually add every "additional" dependency in the Linker section. This requires tracing all the way down the dependency tree, but it does work.

The easier way to do it is add the desired libraries to the "Ignore specific default libraries" field under Linker|Input. For example, I added "Amt.lib", "Bmt.lib", and "Cmt.lib" to that field -- then added "A.lib", "B.lib", and "C.lib" to the "Additional Dependencies" field (also under Linker|Input).